# Reading arrays from .npy files into Fortran 90

Tags: python, arrays, fortran

I am using Python to generate some initial data, in the form of 2D arrays such as 'X', and then using Fortran to do some calculations with them. Initially when the array sizes were around 10,000 x 10,000, np.savetxt worked fine in terms of speed. But once I start increasing the dimensions of the arrays, the speed slows significantly for savetxt. So I tried np.save and this results in much faster saving speeds but the file is saved in the .npy format. How would I go about reading such a file in Fortran to reconstruct the original array? From what I've read, binary usually results in the lowest space consumption and fastest speeds.

In Fortran 90,

```
open(10,file='/home/X.npy')

read(10,*)X
```

I get the following error : Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input

edit : 
In python I do this,

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.linspace(-50,50,10)
y = np.linspace(-50,50,10) 
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
np.save('X',X)
```

Then in Fortran I do this,

```
program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: DPR = selected_real_kind(p=15)
    character(len=*), parameter :: filename = 'X.npy'

    integer, parameter :: N = 10
    real(DPR), allocatable, dimension(:, :) :: X

    allocate(X(N, N))


    open(40, file=filename, status='old', access='stream', form='unformatted')
    read(40) X
    close(40)

    write(*,*) X

end program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
```

The output starts with 1.8758506894003703E-309   1.1711999948023422E+171   5.2274167985502976E-037   8.4474009688929314E+252   2.6514123210345660E+180   9.9215260506210473E+247   2.1620996769994603E+233   7.5805790251297605E-096   3.4756671925988047E-152   6.5549091408576423E-260  -50.000000000000000       -38.888888888888886       -27.777777777777779  and so on

This error doesn't occur when using the .bin format, only when using np.save which results in npy.

Comment: Fortran won't automagically read and correctly interpret arbitrary binary files.  You'll either have to find or write a routine specifically for that format.  It's relatively well-documented and your favourite search engine will help you track down its description.  In passing, the error message suggests that the first 4 (or possibly 8) bytes of the file can't be interpreted as a Fortran `real`.

Comment: Even worse, it has been opened for formatted read in the snippet so it is trying to read a number as text. That can't work. You are speaking about binary, but you did not open the file for binary (unformatted) I/O.

Comment: And always use tag [tag:fortran] so that more people can see your question. Fortran 90 is just one old -now obsolete- version.  Fortran 90 is inadequate for this task, you need stream I/O from Fortran 2003.

Comment: Right, missed that...I also read that HDF5 is really good for handling large data sizes, arising in HPC situations...Do you think that's a good alternative to binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vladimir F is correct that you want 'stream' access of a 'raw binary' file in Fortran. Here's a MWE:

Python

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
print(A.sum())
A.tofile('data.bin')
```

Fortran

```
program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: DPR = selected_real_kind(p=15)
    character(len=*), parameter :: filename = 'data.bin'

    integer, parameter :: N = 10000
    real(DPR), allocatable, dimension(:, :) :: dat

    allocate(dat(N, N))

    open(40, file=filename, status='old', access='stream', form='unformatted')
    read(40) dat
    close(40)

    write(*,*) sum(dat)

end program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
```

My Fortran example is perhaps a bit longer than necessary, as I use many different systems and compiler suites, and also hate large static arrays (I am a Fortran user after all).

I coded this up real quick with Python 2.7.x, Numpy 13.x, and gfortran from Homebrew GCC 6.3.0_1 on a MacBook Pro, but this should work on all systems.

UPDATE:
Special care needs to be taken with the array shapes and sizes here. If `dat` is allocated to be larger than what is in the file, than the streaming `read` should try to fill the entire array, hit the `EOF` symbol, and issue an error. In Python, the `np.fromfile()` method will read up to `EOF` then return a 1D array with the appropriate length, even if `A` was originally multidimensional. This is because a raw binary has no metadata and is simply a contiguous string of bytes from RAM.

As a result, the following lines in Python produce the same file:

```
A = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
A.tofile('file.whatever')
A.ravel().tofile('file.whatever')
A.reshape((100, 1000, 1000)).tofile('file.whatever')
```

And that file can be read in and reshaped as:

```
B = np.fromfile('file.whatever').reshape(A.shape)
B = np.fromfile('file.whatever').reshape((100, 1000, 100, 10))
# or something like
B = np.fromfile('file.whatever') # just a 1D array
B.resize(A.shape)  # resized in-place
```

In Fortran it is easy to read an entire raw file using stream access without knowing its size ahead of time, though you'll obviously need some kind of user input in order to reshape the data:

```
program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: DPR = selected_real_kind(p=15)
    character(len=*), parameter :: filename = 'data.bin'
    integer :: N = 10000, bytes, reals, M
    real(DPR), allocatable :: A(:,:), D(:, :), zeros(:)
    real(DPR), allocatable, target :: B(:)
    real(DPR), pointer :: C(:, :)

    allocate(A(N, N))

    open(40, file=filename, status='old', access='stream', form='unformatted')

    read(40) A
    write(*,*) 'sum of A', sum(A)

    inquire(unit=40, size=bytes)
    reals = bytes/8
    allocate(B(reals))

    read(40, pos=1) B
    write(*,*) 'sum of B', sum(B)

    ! now reshape B in-place assuming the user wants the first dimension 
    ! (which would be the outer dimension in Python) to be length 100
    N = 100
    if(mod(reals, N) == 0) then
         M = reals/N
         call C_F_POINTER (C_LOC(B), C, [N, M])
         write(*, *) 'sum of C', sum(C)
         write(*, *) 'shape of C', shape(C)
    else
         write(*,*) 'file size is not divisible by N!, did not point C to B'
    end if

    ! now reshape B out-of-place with first dimension length 9900, and
    ! pad the result so that there is no size mismatch error  
    N = 9900
    M = reals/N
    if(mod(reals, N) > 0) M=M+1

    allocate(D(N, M))
    allocate(zeros(N), source=real(0.0, DPR))
    D = reshape(B, [N, M], pad=zeros)

    write(*,*) 'sum of D', sum(D)
    write(*,*) 'shape of D', shape(D)

    ! obviously you can also work with shape(A) in fortran the same way you
    ! would use A.shape() in Python, if you already knew that A was the
    ! correct shape of the data
    deallocate(D)
    allocate(D, mold=A)
    D = reshape(B, shape(A))
    write(*,*) 'sum of D', sum(D)
    write(*,*) 'shape of D', shape(D)

    ! or, just directly read it in, skipping the whole reshape B part
    read(40, pos=1) D
    write(*,*) 'sum of D', sum(D)

    close(40)

end program read_unformatted_binary_from_python
```

Comment: There is also apparently a numpy library for use in Fortran to read .npy files. See the bottom of this Cookbook, which includes a download link for libnpy:
http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/InputOutput.html

Comment: Great stuff! I'm not at my pc yet to try this out, but this is backward compatible? As in, will the "stream" work in F 90 or only in 2003 and above? And the libnpy seems like a great tool ,will check that out

Comment: Stream is Fortran 2003. I already said that, so it does not work in Fortran 90. Fortran 90 is obsolete and nobody uses it. Some people use Fortran 95, yes, but usually they have to use many nonstandard extensions in addition. Fortran 90 is just dead. There are no Fortran 90 around except some *very* old versions, so don't worry.

Comment: I see...On another note, when I run the above code with an array of dimensions 10 x 10, with numbers ranging from -50 to 50, and when I write out the array it displays not only the -50 to 50, but also extremely large numbers in the header section. How do I get rid of these so that it doesn't affect further calculations?

Comment: @ThunderFlash I suspect the large number you're seeing is from `write(*,*) sum(dat)`. The array will be of size NxN, and `dat(1,1)` should be the 1st element that was written to the file.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify exactly what you are doing with a MWE by editing your question. My guess is you just need to be careful that you are readin in the same data type in Fortran as your wrote out in Python. The above code works if I do `A = np.arange(-50, 50, dtype=np.float64)` and edit `dat` to be a 100x1 1D array, but not if I do `A = np.arange(-50, 50)` and do not make `dat` an array of 64-bit integers instead of an array of 64-bit floats, since numpy defaults to using np.int64 for np.arange with integer values.

Comment: My bad, seems like the MWE only works with .bin files and not .npy. However, when trying to load the saved array using np.fromfile, the dimensions change to (100,) if the initial array is (10,10)

Comment: See my update above, but TL;DR: a raw binary file has no metadata, so `fromfile()` just reads the data into a contiguous 1D array, but you can always `reshape()` or `resize()` an array

Comment: @CAZT The [scipy cookbook](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/InputOutput.html) you have posted above for libnpy seems to be for saving files from Fortran to .npy, not the other way around.