# Can one save Fortran arrays in .npy format?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, numpy-ndarray

I am using Fortran for my numerical computations. The common standard in Fortran is to save the array as a `.dat` file. I want to occasionally transfer the array to Python for further manipulations. Ways to do this thing

- Write a script in python to read the `.dat`  file  and produce a numpy array
- Use something like HDF5, NETCDF, etc while saving the array (accessible in Python)

`.dat` file script reader would need to be customised t0 the way the arrays are stored. Would need to store probably one array per file for ease of use.
My arrays are not that big so, I am not fond of using HDF5. But do let me know if there is no other option.

This is the opposite of [Reading arrays from .npy files into Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46318178/7952027)

Answer (score 1):

I have not [MRedies NPY-for-Fortran](https://github.com/MRedies/NPY-for-Fortran) used enough yet, but it seems to be what you are looking for.

From the README

> ## NPY for Fortran
>
> This Fortran module allows to save numerical Fortran arrays in Numpy's .npy or .npz format. Currently supported are:
>
> ```
> 1. integer(1), integer(2), integer(4), integer(8)
> 2. real(4), real(8)
> 3. complex(4), complex(8)
> ```
>
> #### *.npy files Saving an array into a .npy-file is simply done by calling:
>
> ```
> call save_npy("filename.npy", array)
> ```

Also, keep an eye out for this [pull request](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib/pull/581) on the [fortran standard library](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib)

Another option, *not tested by me*

> Not my idea  See first [CAZT's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8644947/cazt) comment on [CAZT's  stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333419/7952027)

[libnpy](http://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Emclean/libnpy-0.5.tgz) seems to be a  library that provides simple routines for saving a C or Fortran array to a data file using NumPy's binary format.

> The following is an excerpt from https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/InputOutput.html

```
program fex
    use fnpy
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    integer  :: i
    real(C_DOUBLE) :: a(2,4) = reshape([(i, i=1,8)], [2,4])

    call save_double("fa.npy", shape(a), a)
end program fe
```

The program creates a file `fa.npy` that you can load into python in the usual way.

But the entries of the NumPy array now follow the Fortran (column-major) ordering.

```
>>> fa = np.load('fa.npy')
>>> print fa
[[ 1.  3.  5.  7.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8.]]
```

You can build the executable with `npy.mod` and `libnpy.a` in the same directory as `fex.f95` with the command.

```sh
gfortran -o fex fex.f95 libnpy.a
```

Just for info, I stumbled upon a newer version of `libnpy` at https://github.com/kovalp/libnpy

*Probable bug*

> from [Matthias Redies](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib/pull/581#issuecomment-984476708)
> If you save some array slice `call save_npy(a(:,1,:))` with libnpy you are not going to be happy.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand

Comment: Given the question and answer are from the same person it just looks like an advert to me, especially how it is phrased.

Comment: @VladimirF Is it better now?

Comment: @IanBush  I am not the owner of any of these libraries so, why would I advertise?

Comment: It really looks like one at first site. They are quite common on SO. The answer is certainly better now. Given that the pull request is active in recent hours it may have been wiser to wait a bit for the result but it should be fine if you update your answer with the outcome.

Comment: @VladimirF I will update it with the current status of the pull request.

Comment: BTW even the library author can answer this way, it is allowed. The main point is to say "you can do it this way using this library', not just "here is a link to a library that can do it".